# Jquery notificações simultâneas duplicadas de chat

Tags: jquery, chat, notificação

Olá,
Tenho um sistema de chat que dá notificações em qualquer parte do site em qual esteja ou na página mesma do chatt, entanto quanto estou com 2 abas abertas recebo notificação em ambas, ou seja, duplicado, teria alguma forma de verificar se tenho mais de 2 abas abertas do mesmo site no navegador para poder fazer um filtro e mostrar somente em uma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro alterar o seu serviço que retorna as mensagem que serão notificadas, para que, ao retornar uma mensagem, já marque ela como "lida" (um campo a mais da tabela da mensagem). E ao retornar as mensagens, você busque apenas as mensagens ainda não lidas.

Dessa forma quando a primeira aba receber as mensagens e mostrar elas na tela, elas serão marcadas como lidas no servidor. E a segunda aba não receberá nenhuma mensagem, pois já estarão todas como lidas.

Comment: Obrigada, irei tentar.